# Authorize Endpoint URL and Token Endpoint URL in Open ID Connect

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, lightning-connect

I need to create an External Data Source to connect to third party system and I am doing it with OAuth mechanism.I need to create Authentication Provider with type as Open ID Connect before doing it.I have URL with which I can get access token by passing Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Username and Password.I believe this is Token Endpoint URL.I can make subsequent calls successfully using the token.I don't understand what needs to be passed for Authorize Endpoint URL in Auth Provider screen.Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the third party system you are connecting to.  For example, for Google it would be https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth.  This gives you an authorization code that you can exchange for an access token at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence for the reply.Actually it is a java application that I need to connect to and I was given one URL to fetch the token(https://mycompany.com/login/v1.1/token.oauth2) and another URL(http://mycompany.com/si/v3/ppf/PeopleFinderService/peoplefinderservice.svc/) to fetch the data using the token.I believe the URL to fetch token is Token Endpoint URL.Please confirm.Also let me know what should be passed to Authorize Endpoint URL

Comment: It seems some changes need to be done at external system.It is not following standard OAuth flow